# About the domension of a Moduli space of surface of general type

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I hope this question is suitable for this site and not too easy. It is just about a knoledge of well known results about moduli spaces of complex algebraic surfaces.
With the notation $\mathcal{M}_{K^2,\chi}$ i mean the moduli space of a surface of general type (surface: complex algebraic ) with the invariants $K^2$ and $\chi$ fixed. I've seen that there is an inequality for that moduli space dimension due to Castelnuovo that is $$dim \mathcal{M}_{K^2, \chi}\ge 10\chi -2K^2$$.
If i want to compute directly the dimension of $\mathcal{M}_{K^2,\chi}$  How can i do it?
Maybe useful.

This question rises up from that problem: i know the value of the second term of the previous inequality (48). I know the dimension of the space $H^1(S,T_S)$ where $S$ is a canonical surface and $T$ the tangent bundle (64). Knowing that parameters can i find the dimension of the moduli space of my surface?

Comment: This is, obviously, just a comment, and may not be helpful to you. But, you're really asking a deformation theory question (assuming that this moduli space is smooth, which it is if memory serves). Namely, you're asking for the dimension of the deformations of curves with these fixed invariants. So, a good place to look would be a book on deformation theory/algebraic surfaces to see if you can find a deformation space (i.e. tangent space) for deformations of surfaces with these invariants.